# My basic binary search method does not work for one specific value in an int array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, search, binary, int

I'm a beginner java learner and here's a little program that outputs the index of a searched int value in an int array. Here is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int rank =findNumber(7, new int[]{2, 4, 7, 10, 11, 45, 50, 59, 60, 66, 69, 70, 79});
    System.out.println("Your number's index is " + rank);

}

public static int findNumber(int key, int... numbers) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = numbers.length - 1;
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    int rank = 0;
    for (int i = low; i < high; i++) {
        if (key < numbers[mid]) {
            high = mid;
            mid = (low + high) / 2;
        } else if (key > numbers[mid]) {
            low = mid;
            mid = (low + high) / 2;
        } else {
            rank = mid;
            return rank;
        }
    }
    return rank;
}
```

The problem is it works for all numbers in the array, except 7. I tried to find it by debugging but came up with nothing.

Can anyone tell me what's the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that even though you're changing `low` and `high`, the loop depends on variable `i` which only changes through being incremented at the end of each iteration of the loop. However, the terminating condition for binary search should be when `low >= high`. The loop condition you have now, `i < high` has nothing to do with the relationship between `low` and `high`, which could cause the loop to end prematurely or keep going when the binary search has already ended.

What I'd suggest is doing is initializing `low` in the for loop, changing the terminating condition to `low <= high`, and making the update sequence `mid = (low + high)/2` since you do that after each iteration of the for loop unless you find the number. At that point, however, the loop will terminate returning the index of the found number. Here's what it would look like,

```
public static int findNumber(int key, int... numbers) {
    int high = numbers.length - 1;
    int mid = (0 + high) / 2; //replaced low with 0 here
    int rank = 0;
    for (int low = 0; low <= high; mid = (low + high) / 2) {
        if (key < numbers[mid]) {
            high = mid - 1;
        } else if (key > numbers[mid]) {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else {
            rank = mid;
            return rank;
        }
    }
    return rank;
}
```

**EDIT:** So after some testing, I realized that another error was how you were updating `low` and `high` in your method. When updating these variables before, you were simply doing `high = mid` and `low = mid` but this is risky because by doing this, you're essentially still keeping `numbers[mid]` within the range that's going to be evaluated in the next iteration of the loop. This number, `numbers[mid]` should be omitted from the range, since the key is either going to be less than, greater than, or equal to `numbers[mid]`. If the key is less than or greater than `numbers[mid]`, then there's no point in keeping it going forward to the next range of numbers to be looked at by binary search. So a solution would be to update low and high by `low = mid + 1` and `high = mid - 1`.

Comment: took me a while to figure out but I believe I fixed it!

Comment: To be honest, i was completely unaware of the behaviour of `i` until i see  your explanation. That was the main cause of undetection of index for number 7. `i` was simply exceeding it's `high` limit and the loop was terminating prematurely, as you've described. Also your solution for end values works great with `high>=low`. That's the iteration the program exactly needs to catch any values. Thank you very much for your great explanation and time

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the stopping condition is off. It may be easier to think of the stopping condition differently. Change the upper and lower bounds so you search "halves" of the array. When do you know the item you are trying to find doesn't exist in the array? That is when the indices cross. low is greater than high. `(while low <= high) { ... }` In that case, you could return a dummy value that you know shouldn't exist in the array. For example, if you only store positive values, return -1. Otherwise you could return an Integer (non-primitive type) to represent an index, and if an item cannot be found, specifically `null`.

Comment: what if key doesn't exists? infinite loop

Comment: Yeah the main problem was the incorrect set up of boundaries and since i was struggling with that, i couldn't even see that there was no any dummy value for "key non-exists" cases. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your `for` loop is slightly wrong. Instead of

```
for (int i = low; i < high; i++)
```

it should be:

```
for (int i = low; i <= high; i++)
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem is with the `for` loop. You're limiting the number of loop passes to `high`, but `high` gets changed from within the loop. Did you mean something like `for (int i = low; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) { ... }`?

Comment: No, the loop boundaries was _intended_ to be changed by each iteration since it's aim is to make the key value a middle of some two upper and lower boundries

Comment: I'm afraid you're misunderstanding how binary search works. You don't even use `i` inside the loop. As an exercise, try to replace your `for` with what I proposed and see for yourself. :)

Comment: He understud it better than you ... your loop would unnecesery checks if key does not exists [his fixed code](http://ideone.com/XUse60) vs [your code](http://ideone.com/WGFfLa)

Comment: @Selvin The current algorithm doesn't really handle the case when the looked-up value is not present. It returns 0, which suggests that the element exists as the first element of the array. In fact, the fact that this algorithm works for the value '2' is a coincidence. The algorithm (incorrectly) doesn't find the value, so it returns 0, which happens to be the correct answer. To see that just change the last `return rank;` to `-1` and then test `findNumber(2, new int[]{2, 4, 7, 10, 11, 45, 50, 59, 60, 66, 69, 70, 79});`. It'll return -1. See [here](http://ideone.com/Myi7nc).

Comment: good point ... on the other hand changing to `i < numbers.length - 1` will not find 79  http://ideone.com/frBSCg

Comment: @Selvin You're right, but that's due to an unrelated bug in the original code. The original algorithm doesn't find it either. Even after your fix.

Comment: yeah .. there is no god answer yet :)

Comment: @korolar Actually i knew that it doesn't work for initial and final values but i had given up with them since the `7` case was tiring me enough :) Anyway, since we got a good solution, no problem's left. Thank you for your time and interest